# CSS & React / Transition to change background color and font color isn't working

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, css-transitions

I am trying to have an effect on hover, to change the background color and font color in a react application.

Here's react component I have:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import styles from './Project.module.scss'

let Project = function(props){
    return (
        <div className={styles.Project}>
            <h1>{props.Title}</h1>
            <h4>{props.Budget? props.Budget: 'No budget specificed'}</h4>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Project
```

and here's my Project.module.scss code:

```
.Project{
    width: 45%; 
    box-shadow: 1px 1px grey;
    border: 2px solid grey; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
    background-color: white;
    transition: all 2 ease;
    transition-property: background-color, color;
    -webkit-transition: all 2 ease;
    -webkit-transition-property:  background-color, color;

    &:hover{
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
}
```

All properties seem to work except for the transition for both background color and color.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `-webkit-transition: all 2s ease;` it is `2s`

Comment: Can you please post it as an answer? it worked.

Comment: Added as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
```

you need to add `s` with the transition time. It represent `seconds`